# Create form without JavaScript

Tags: forms

I'm quite new in Drupal and I have to create a register form with dropdown lists like (Country->Province->City) but I can not use javascript, jquery or ajax due to accessibility issues. Is there any way to create it?

Some tips are welcome!

Comment: It is not possible to build dependent select lists without javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. JavaScript is the only way to have content (including forms) change on a page without relaod. Now you have two ways to go around it:

1. Make all choices available in all 3 downloads and only hide unneeded ones using JavaScript. That way if someone will not have JS enabled, he will see all choices and will be able to make his selection. Don't forget to test if his selection is sane on the server side!
2. Use multi-step form. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/135/16495) and accepted answer. That way you will be able to ask one thing at a time, serving new steps using good old HTTP.

Comment: In my case, I could reload the page or create a "refresh button". By refreshing the page, is there any another method? The last option would be the multi-step form.

Comment: @Luismin If you can reload page, then multistep is for you. just make other fields appear on all steps. That'll do it.